# Does a burrowing creature provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

Does a creature provoke opportunity attacks when it leaves a threatened square adjacent to an enemy by burrowing?

*See [this closed question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/burrowing-large-creatures-opportunity-attacks-drowning-and-z-axis-movement) for prior discussion on the topic of burrowing.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

> ***Opportunity Attack*** <sup>[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=331)</sup>
>
> *Moving Provokes:* If an enemy leaves a square adjacent to you, you can make an opportunity attack against that enemy. However, you can’t make one if the enemy shifts or teleports or is forced to move away by a pull, a push, or a slide.

Exception does not include burrowing. But more importantly:

> *Interrupts Target’s Action:* An opportunity action takes place *before* the target finishes its action. After the opportunity attack, the creature resumes its action.

The interrupt (not a reaction) is key. So before the burrowing happens, the `Opportunity Attack` happens.

There is some clarity in the power description:

> ***Burrowing Speed*** <sup>[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=345)</sup>
>
> A creature that has a burrow speed can move through loose earth at a specified speed, and the creature can move through solid stone at half that speed. The creature can’t *shift* or charge while burrowing.

The reason to prohibit shifting during burrowing is to explicitly *allow* for
`Opportunity Attacks`.

Comment: But what happens if the creature is already in the ground?

Comment: @SteveC Assuming the attacker is on the surface and has no special abilities to the contrary, a burrowed creature would not be in "threatened square", since there is blocking terrain between them.

Answer (score 0):

... most likely ... **No**

*This is assuming the creature is in an adjacent **ground** square, not in an adjacent **open air** square, in which case the answer is ... **Yes***

Unless the square of ground the monster is burrowed in is transparent, there is no `Opportunity Attack` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=glossary&id=331)]

> **Able to Attack:** You can’t make an opportunity attack unless you are able to make a melee basic attack and you can see your enemy.

Comment: This certainly applies to a creature that is not leaving an adjacent square, but rather tunnelling under you, but since OA's interrupt (and in the case of fighters can prevent) movement away, the OA should happen before the target is burrowing and therefore before LOS is lost, in the "burrow away" scenario in the question.

Comment: @SimonWithers The notes in the On-line Compendium suggest that a creature can have bother a **Burrow** speed, and the **Tunneling** effect ... *yeap, just checked and e.g. Lesser Earth Elemental only has **Burrow** whereas Hive Worker has **Burrow (Tunneling)** as one its Speeds* ... in the 3D 4E burrowing underneath you is still an adjacent square

Comment: Ok, why the negative votes ??

Comment: @SteveC Adjacent spaces are not always "threatened" (LOS/LOE) and subject to OA, though I can see how this case is a little persnickety. Thin walls are still walls. I hate -1 votes too, btw.