# Is a creature's Z-axis tracked while it burrows?

Tags: dnd-4e

When a creature uses the `burrow` movement mode, should its Z-axis position be tracked, much like it would be if it were using the `fly` movement mode?

Consider the Warden power **Shake the Earth** from the Earth Shaker Paragon Path described in *Primal Power*:

> Close Burst 4
>   If the target is burrowing, you slide it 4 squares to the square nearest to it that is within your line of effect.

This seems to suggest that Z-axis is tracked and that a creature up to 4 squares deep underground would be slid directly upwards to the surface of the ground. If Z-axis is not tracked, what does the 4 squares of sliding imply?

*See [this closed question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/burrowing-large-creatures-opportunity-attacks-drowning-and-z-axis-movement) for prior discussion on the topic of burrowing.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

All movement is tracked, even if it is activated by the burrow ability. Same goes for levitation and spring traps.

Answer (score 0):

**The Z-axis is tracked**

So the `Forced Movement` would be handled the same as with horizontal `Slides`