# What actions can a burrowed creature take while burrowed?

Tags: dnd-4e

*Monster Manual 1* states:

> **Burrow [Movement Mode]:** A monster with a burrow speed can move through loose earth at the stated speed and move through solid stone at one-half its burrow speed. A monster can't shift or charge while burrowing.
>   A monster can't be seen while it's burrowing, but it can be heard with a successful Perception check (opposed by the monster's Stealth check).

Because a Stealth check can only be made at the end of a movement, presumably a creature with burrow can end its movement burrowed underground, making the mentioned Stealth check. However, once movement ends and the creature is still burrowed, what actions can it take? It cannot shift or charge, but can it jump, attack, or use powers?

*See [this closed question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/burrowing-large-creatures-opportunity-attacks-drowning-and-z-axis-movement) for prior discussion on the topic of burrowing.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

The exclusion is the `Shift` and `Charge` can't be used, so other things can

That said, things like `Line of Effect`, `Line of Sight` are going to be difficult with all that `Blocking Terrain` around it  :-)

Comment: Tremorsense helps with line of site. But line of effect is a harder problem.