# Can a creature burrow through walls or ceilings?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

**Burrow** allows a creature to move through solid stone at one half its burrow speed. Does this also allow a creature to move through non-floor surfaces, such as walls? Could a creature with burrow travel through the city walls into a city?

Does burrowing through vertical surfaces allow vertical movement? Could a creature with burrow move into the city walls, then up to the allure behind the battlements?

If a creature can burrow up a vertical surface, can it also burrow through a stone ceiling? Could it then drop down on an enemy below, or travel up to the floor of the room above?

*See [this closed question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/burrowing-large-creatures-opportunity-attacks-drowning-and-z-axis-movement) for prior discussion on the topic of burrowing.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

The `Burrow Speed` is analogous to the other `Special Movement Modes`, Rules Compendium, p.202, like `Fly Speed` and `Climb Speed`

There is no restriction that it is only horizontal movement

> **Burrow speed**
>   A creature that has a burrow speed can move through loose earth at a specified speed, and the creature can move through solid stone at half that speed. The creature can’t shift or charge while burrowing.

Comment: @Soulrift: Most walls and ceilings won't be made of loose earth.

Comment: @Zachiel  Agreed ... but the Burrow speed still allows them to go through solid stone at half speed

Comment: Yes yes it was just a reminder for Soulrift ;)